# Throws exception on applying grouping_id on cube result in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to apply grouping_id on result applying cube. But it throws an error.

Dataframe:

```
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+----------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|         Description|Quantity|        InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerID|       Country|      date|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+----------+
|   536365|   85123A|WHITE HANGING HEA...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     2.55|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|    71053| WHITE METAL LANTERN|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|   84406B|CREAM CUPID HEART...|       8|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     2.75|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|   84029G|KNITTED UNION FLA...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|   84029E|RED WOOLLY HOTTIE...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

Query:

```
dfWithDate.cube("CustomerId", "StockCode").agg(grouping_id(), sum("Quantity")).orderBy(expr("grouping_id()").desc)
    .show()
```

But it throws an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping()/grouping_id() can only be used with GroupingSets/Cube/Rollup;
```

I am not sure where I am making mistake. I have applied grouping_id after cube that's why I am not able to detect error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of `Spark` do you use? I can't reproduce your exception on `2.4.3`

Comment: @Gelerion Thanks for the quick response. I am using 2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result via the following operations:

```
b.cube("CustomerId", "StockCode").agg(grouping_id(), sum("Quantity")).orderBy($"grouping_id()".desc).show()
```

Or

```
b.cube("CustomerId", "StockCode").agg(grouping_id(), sum("Quantity")).orderBy(desc("grouping_id()")).show()
```

The result will be:

```
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|CustomerId|StockCode|grouping_id()|sum(Quantity)|
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|      null|     null|            3|           32|
|      null|   84029G|            2|            6|
|      null|   84406B|            2|            8|
|      null|   84029E|            2|            6|
|      null|   85123A|            2|            6|
|      null|    71053|            2|            6|
|   17850.0|     null|            1|           32|
|   17850.0|   84406B|            0|            8|
|   17850.0|   85123A|            0|            6|
|   17850.0|   84029E|            0|            6|
|   17850.0|   84029G|            0|            6|
|   17850.0|    71053|            0|            6|
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: @himansiIIItian Second answer worked for me. But for first response there is compilation error in .orderBy($"grouping_id()".desc).

Answer (score 1):

> spark 2.3.1 [multi-dimension aggregation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-multi-dimensional-aggregation.html) please prefer this link as well

```
var df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((536365,"85123A","WHITE HANGING HEA...",6,"2010-12-01 08:26:00",2.55,17850.0,"United Kingdom","2010-12-01"),(536365, "71053"," WHITE METAL LANTERN",6,"2010-12-01 08:26:00",3.39,17850.0,"United Kingdom","2010-12-01"),(536365,"84406B","CREAM CUPID HEART",8,"2010-12-01 08:26:00",2.75,17850.0,"United Kingdom","2010-12-01"),(536365,"84029G","KNITTED UNION FLA",6,"2010-12-01 08:26:00",3.39,17850.0,"United Kingdom","2010-12-01"),(536365,"84029E","RED WOOLLY HOTTIE",6,"2010-12-01 08:26:00",3.39,17850.0,"United Kingdom","2010-12-01"))).toDF("InvoiceNo","StockCode","Description","Quantity","InvoiceDate","UnitPrice","CustomerID","Country","date")
scala> df.show
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+----------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|         Description|Quantity|        InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerID|       Country|      date|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+----------+
|   536365|   85123A|WHITE HANGING HEA...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     2.55|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|    71053| WHITE METAL LANTERN|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|   84406B|   CREAM CUPID HEART|       8|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     2.75|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|   84029G|   KNITTED UNION FLA|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
|   536365|   84029E|   RED WOOLLY HOTTIE|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|2010-12-01|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+----------+


scala> val df_grp_id = df.cube("CustomerId", "StockCode") .agg(sum("Quantity") ,grouping_id() as "gid") .orderBy($"gid".desc).drop($"gid")


scala> df_grp_id.show
+----------+---------+-------------+
|CustomerId|StockCode|sum(Quantity)|
+----------+---------+-------------+
|      null|     null|           32|
|      null|    71053|            6|
|      null|   85123A|            6|
|      null|   84029G|            6|
|      null|   84406B|            8|
|      null|   84029E|            6|
|   17850.0|     null|           32|
|   17850.0|   85123A|            6|
|   17850.0|   84406B|            8|
|   17850.0|    71053|            6|
|   17850.0|   84029G|            6|
|   17850.0|   84029E|            6|
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

try this it will resolve your problem if it's your solution accept the answer. let me know if you again face issue in same. HAppy Hadoop

Comment: thanks for the response but it gives compilation error in orderBy

Comment: Cannot paste screenshot here. But error says Cannot resolve overloaded method 'orderBy'

Comment: could you please add those log into your question part to check.